# Remove straight grid-lines and change label in polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can i remove the straight lines (from 45 to 225 degree and 135 to 315 degree) and change the axis labeling to 0, pi/2 , pi, 3/2*pi in the following code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rmax(2)
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])  # Less radial ticks
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)  # Move radial labels away from plotted line
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 4, endpoint=False))` and `ax.set_xticklabels([<whatever you want>])`

Comment: Thx do u also know how to remove the straight lines in the grid, so that only the circles remain.